# Dimdim Change name

Tags: java, web-applications, streaming

i build dimdim v4.5 on my pc 
and its work fine with me. 
each time i want to start meeting i type my pc IP address like this :

`http://<my-ip-address>/dimdim`

i want to change the word dimdim to be anything else

like :

`http://<my-ip-address>/meeting`

i try to change the fodler called dimdim  to

also there is file in

/usr/local/dimdim/ConferenceServer/apache-tomcat-5.5.17/webapps/dimdim/WEB-INF/classes/resources/dimdim.properties

and thry to change webapps name 
but not work

regards

Answer (score 0):

dimdim is the web app name, we can rename the web app name to whatever we need.

this is by rename the folder "dimdim" tunder TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/dimdim to TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/xyz

and then the url will become ip-address/xyz